# Run code on WinForms app close and computer shutdown?

Tags: c#, winforms, shutdown

I want my C# WinForms app to run some code when either the app is closed, or the computer is shutdown (via the startmenu, I know it wont work if they pull the plug :P).

Basically I have some log files that I need the app to upload to an FTP server on shutdown.

How can I do this?

Comment: @BryanCrosby `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler (OnExit);` and using the form's `FormClosing` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect your application shutting down by either intercepting the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event.

You can detect widows shutdown, logoff, suspend, etc using [SystemEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx). I recommend not using the system events as you may not get enough time to perform an upload to a remote server (I think the default is 3 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Hook your form's [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event. This will be fired any time the form closes, whether in response to the user closing it, the program calling Close, Windows shutting down, etc.

If you need to know which sort of exit you're dealing with, the [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) has a CloseReason property (of type [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx)) that will tell you why the window is being closed; it includes values like UserClosing and WindowsShutDown.

You may not be able to upload to an FTP server on Windows shutdown, though. In Windows Vista and 7, apps only get 2 seconds to shut down before Windows reserves the right to forcibly terminate them. You might be better off saving your log locally, and uploading it the next time your app starts.

Comment: Yea I've already tried using the `FormClosing` event, although I had never thought about just uploading the file when the computer starts back up. I'll try adding a little tag at the end of the file to let the program know that the file still needs to be uploaded. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, sorry to accept your answer, then un-accept, but someone found out how to get it working on shutdown/logoff.

Comment: @ryansworld10, interesting. So doing your upload from SystemEvents works better than doing it from FormClosing? I didn't expect that (though it's certainly possible), so I'm curious to know more. I would have thought the 2-second cutoff would apply either way.

Comment: From what I can tell, Windows is giving my app enough time to complete the upload. I have tested it multiple times on multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should concentrate on doing your upload on shutting down of your app and not on shutting down of computer because when a computer is shutting down it will not have enough resources & time to do your work(upload and stuff). Use the Form_Closing event of your app to do your work when app's closing is called or you can use Form_Closed event to fire when your app is about to close.

[Closing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx)
[Closed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx)

Comment: I need to do the uploading on shutdown, because the user isn't interacting with my app. It is hidden and runs in the background.

Comment: You linked to WPF events. The question is about WinForms.

Comment: Do go verbatim. Important is logic, algo